# Replace first character of string

Tags: javascript

I have a string   `|0|0|0|0`

but it needs to be `0|0|0|0`

How do I replace the first character (`'|'`) with (`''`).  eg  `replace('|','')`

(with JavaScript)

Comment: This is a common misconception coming from other languages, in JavaScript the `.replace()` method doesn't replace *all* occurrences (unless you use `/g`), it only replaces the **first** occurence: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You can do exactly what you have :)

```
var string = "|0|0|0|0";
var newString = string.replace('|','');
alert(newString); // 0|0|0|0
```

[You can see it working here](http://jsfiddle.net/GS8Sj/), `.replace()` in javascript only replaces the first occurrence by default (without `/g`), so this works to your advantage :)

If you need to check if the first character is a pipe:

```
var string = "|0|0|0|0";
var newString = string.indexOf('|') == 0 ? string.substring(1) : string;
alert(newString); // 0|0|0|0​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

[You can see the result here](http://jsfiddle.net/GS8Sj/1/)

Comment: @MgS: Test it - `.replace()` only replaces the first occurence, do you want to remove the `|` only if it's leading?  I updated the answer to reflect this option as well :)

Comment: @Justin - thanks! it was a mis-paste, fixed it in the answer.

Answer (score 30):

```
str.replace(/^\|/, "");
```

This will remove the first character if it's a |.

Answer (score 26):

```
var newstring = oldstring.substring(1);
```

Comment: If the string is 0|0|0|0 then it will remove the first 0

Comment: @MgS, true. So check first to see what the first character is.

Comment: @Mgs The title of the question asks how to remove the first character, not remove the first instance of a specific character.  This is the general solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not sure what the first character will be ( 0 or | ) then the following makes sense:

```
// CASE 1:
var str = '|0|0|0';
str.indexOf( '|' ) == 0 ? str = str.replace( '|', '' ) : str;
// str == '0|0|0'

// CASE 2:
var str = '0|0|0';
str.indexOf( '|' ) == 0? str = str.replace( '|', '' ) : str;
// str == '0|0|0'
```

Without the conditional check, str.replace will still remove the first occurrence of '|' even if it is not the first character in the string. This will give you undesired results in  the case of CASE 2 ( str will be '00|0' ).

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```js
var str = "|0|0|0|0";
str.replace(str.charAt(0), "");
```

Avoid using [`substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) as it's considered [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr#Browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 1):

It literally is what you suggested.

```
"|0|0|0".replace('|', '')
```

returns `"0|0|0"`

Comment: If string is 0|0|0 then it will remove the first 0

Answer (score 0):

We don't want to delete the next pipe in case if string doesn't start with it. Then Mathew Flaschen's regex approach is a good solution. Without regex;

```
  str = str[0] == "/"? str.replace("/", ""):str;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
"|0|0|0|0".split("").reverse().join("")  //can also reverse the string => 0|0|0|0|
```