# Javascript Replace, string with comma

Tags: javascript, replace

I have a string that contains multiple occurrences of `],[` that I want to replace with `]@[`

No matter what I try I cant get it right.

```
    var find = '],[';
    var regex = new RegExp(find, "g");
    mytext.replace(regex, ']@[')
```

Doesn't work

```
   mytext = mytext.replace(/],[/g,']@[');
```

Doesn't work

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: Please check out the following jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JspRR/3/ to verify my answer.

Comment: The answer is that [ and ] are special characters in the context of regular expressions and as such need to be escaped either by means of \ i.e. to match ] you write  \[

Comment: @MiltiadisKokkonidis It is working fine for me and replaces ALL occurrences.I didn't mark it accepted until I used his code and found it solved my issue.

Comment: Please have a look at the following jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JspRR/6/  The version with the global regex does what you want, but the one with the string does not, right?

Comment: Also you may have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992276/replace-first-character-of-string

Comment: Correct, but I took it that the regex version was the solution and it does solve my problem.  There was another answer (now removed) where I commented that the string one was not working and only replaced the first occurrence.  Bruno was the first to post a working solution to my problem with an explanation where I went wrong.

Comment: Bruno's recommendation was mytext.replace("],[", "]@[");  Did you try that or change your regular expression (which does work)?  javascript: (alert("[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]".replace("],[","]@["))) pops-up an alert showing "[1]@[2],[3],[4],[5]", not "[1]@[2]@[3]@[4]@[5]" ...

Comment: His post starts with: "Does the same without regex
mytext.replace("],[", "]@[");"  This is the very first thing he recommends, the very first things someone sees, and exactly the kind of misconception that will get anyone new to JavaScript writing incorrect code.  Moreover if someone does a test to see if a single occurence is replaced they will think the code works and has been tested too.  Sorry I am going on and on about this, but this is perhaps my worst Javascript greavance

Comment: As I said the regex version, he corrected my regex example in the original question and it worked. He didn't recommend anything but he did show me why my regex was not working and corrected it.  However I don't really think this is the place to have this discussion.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments and I have corrected my code. Because the comments were added here I wasn't notified that the first section of my answer wasn't correct until Fred posted a comment under my answer( Thanks Fred ). In future, go direct to the source and make a comment under their answer and you will find that people will be more than happy to amend their code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your example doesn't work is because normally square brackets represents a character class and therefore you need to escape them like so

```
var find = '\\],\\[';
var regex = new RegExp(find, "g");
mytext.replace(regex, ']@[')
```

You can also use a regex literal

```
mytext.replace(/\],\[/g, "]@[");
```

Comment: First answer that worked plus an explanation where I went wrong.  Many thanks

Comment: Please see comments above and highlight the working version  for anyone that views this accepted answer.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that [ and ] are special characters in the context of regular expressions and as such need to be escaped either by means of \ i.e. to match ] you write  [ when you use the convenient Javascript shorthand for regular expressions that you can find in the code below:

```
var regex= /\],\[/g
var result = mytext.replace(regex, ']@[')
```

Please check out the following jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JspRR/4/

As you can see the important bit is escaping the ] and the [ when constructing the regular expression.

Now if you did not want to use the Javascript regular expressions shorthand, you would still need to have the same escaping.  However, in that case the \ character will need to be escaped itself ( ... by itself!)

```
var regex = new RegExp("\\],\\[", "g");
var result = mytext.replace(regex, ']@[')
```

Answer (score 1):

Square brackets are special characters inside a regular expression: they are used to define a character set.

If you want to match square brackets in a regexp, you have to escape them, using back slash.

```
"[1],[2],[3]".replace(/\],\[/g, "]@[");
```

Or, in case you use the builtin constructor:

```
"[1],[2],[3]".replace(new RegExp("\\],\\[", "g"), "]@[");
```

In both case we have to use the `g` flag so that the regular expression can match all the occurrences of the searched string.

```js
var str = "[1],[2],[3]";

console.log(str.replace(/\],\[/g, "]@["));
console.log(str.replace(new RegExp("\\],\\[", "g"), "]@["));
```

Comment: Just correct regexp will be `.replace(/\],\[/g,"]@[")` (] and [ should be escaped)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
 mytext.replace(/\],\[/g, ']@[')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "[1],[2],[3]";

var replaced = str.replace('],[', ']@[');
```