# Javascript replace first letter of every string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to make a script that should replace strings. This is what my current replace function does:

```
let message2 = message1.replace(/hello/g, "[size=medium]h[/size]ello");
```

As you can see, this adds the `size=medium` tag to the `h` of the word. This works good, but I want this to work in every possible capitalization and still *remain* in that capitalization.

For example:
`"hELLo"` should be replaced with `"[size=medium]h[/size]ELLo"`

and

`"HELLo"` be replaced with `"[size=medium]H[/size]ELLo"`

Only the `h`/`H` should be wrapped in the tag, but I am not sure how to perform something like this. Big thanks for any input on this!

Comment: You mean "HELLo" be replaced with "[size=medium]H[/size]ELLo"?

Comment: Yes you are correct. Sorry i realized this just now as well @CuongLeNgoc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace first character of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992276/replace-first-character-of-string)

Comment: Are you looking to do this only for the word "hello" and any variations of it, or do you mean to do this for every word? Also can you clarify what you mean by "word"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use capture groups:

```
message1.replace(/(h)(ello)/ig, "[size=medium]$1[/size]$2")
```

Or alternatively, look-ahead:

```
message1.replace(/h(?=ello)/ig, "[size=medium]$&[/size]")
```

Comment: In case of `message1 = "ahello"`, it still replace the `h` letter.

Comment: But the question is replace the first letter.

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc `h` is the first letter of the string `hello`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regex:

```js
var a = 'hello';
var b = 'HEllo';

console.log(a.replace(/^h/i, "[size=medium]$&[/size]"))
console.log(b.replace(/^h/i, "[size=medium]$&[/size]"))
```

Of if you just want to replace `h` in `hello`, you can use look ahead:

```js
var a = 'HEllo';
var b = 'Halo';

console.log(a.replace(/^h(?=ello)/i, "[size=medium]$&[/size]"))
console.log(b.replace(/^h(?=ello)/i, "[size=medium]$&[/size]"))
```

Comment: Because the capture group is the full match, you can use `$&` instead (and remove the capture group entirely). If it's desired to only replace `h`s which end in `ello` you can lookahead for the `ello`